# Problem with (NASM) assembly program to output the bigger of 2 numbers

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm trying to make a program that compares two numbers, x and y (predefined in the code) and outputs a message saying "The biggest number is " and then the bigger one. However, it has a pretty weird bug that is hard to explain.

1. If the output message is "The biggest number is ", it ALWAYS takes x as the biggest number and outputs that. It also outputs an h before the message, so it says "hThe biggest number is x"
2. If I add any character before the T in "The", it ALWAYS takes y as the biggest one, and still outputs an h before the message, such as "hdThe biggest number is y"

Of course, if I put other characters in the message it also messes things up. Here is my code:

```
section .text

global _start

_start:

mov     eax, [x]
sub     eax, '0'
mov     ebx, [y]
sub     ebx, '0'
cmp     eax, ebx
ja     case1

case2: add     ebx, '0'
mov [big], ebx
jmp next

case1:  add     eax, '0'
mov [big], eax

next: mov     ecx, msg
mov     edx, len
call cout

mov     ecx, big
mov     edx, 1
call cout

mov     eax, 1
int     0x80

cout: mov ebx, 1
      mov eax, 4
      int 0x80
      ret

section .data
big db 0
x db '9'
y db '8'
msg db  "The biggest number is "
len equ $ - msg

segment .bss

sum resb 1
```

Comment: `mov eax, [x]` is moving 4 bytes from location `x` to `eax`. Likewise many of your other instructions.  `mov [big], eax` moves 4 bytes out to location `big`, so you're overwriting `x`, `y`, and the first byte of `msg`. To compare your bytes, use byte registers: `mov al, [x]` then `sub al, '0'`, ..., `cmp al, bl`.